# Get per-request dependency from an Autofac func factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm using ASP.NET Core and Autofac. Almost everything is registered as per lifetime scope ("per request"). So my database context `DbContext` is the same instance throughout a request.

However I have a singleton which also depends on `DbContext`. To avoid a captive dependency, it is injected as `Func<Owned<DbContext>>`, which means a new `DbContext` instance each time.

The problem is I need the same instance, as everywhere else during the request, not a new one.

I want to avoid a captive dependency bug, but I also want the same instance. Is that possible via tagging or a custom registration?

Comment: Can't you redesign your singleton service to reverse the dependencies? If it really needs a DbContext why is it singleton in the first place?

Comment: @Tseng No I can't unfortunately. It's a FluentValidation validator with dozens of lambda expressions, which need to be compiled and cached, just once.

Comment: But doesn't prevent it from being refactored. Dunno how your singleton service looks like, but it may make sense to split the fluent validation into its own singleton service and then inject it with the DbContext into a scoped service which you use instead. But hard to give you concrete tips without more information

Comment: @Tseng the singleton service is a validator class, registered and used by the FluentValidation library. There's not much I can do on that side of things. This particular validator needs to check something in the database, before it makes a decision, which is why the DbContext is injected. But I want the same instance as everywhere else, not a new one.

Comment: Well, a concrete example of the class and it's usage would be useful, but there is still the "bruteforce" method available: Inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` and resolve the DbContext from there and you'll always have the scoped one (except when the validator is called outside of a request, i.e. by a background running task - which you should already avoid inside ASP.NET (Core) Apps). But it's pretty brute and ties your validator to the infrastructure (ASP.NET Core/HttpAbstraction library). Or create a `Scoped<T>` class and inject it (like you did with Owned<T>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments the least "architectural" painful approach may be by creating your own `Scoped<T>` class which will resolve the DbContext from current `HttpContext`

```
// Use an interface, so we don't have infrastructure dependencies in our domain
public interface IScoped<T> where T : class
{
    T Instance { get; }
}

// Register as singleton too.
public sealed class Scoped<T> : IScoped<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; } => contextAccessor.HttpContext;

    public T Instance { get; } => HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<T>();

    public Scoped(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
    }
}
```

Register it as

```
// Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IScoped<>), typeof(Scoped<>);
// Autofac
containerBuilder.RegisterType(typeof(Scoped<>))
            .As(typeof(IScoped<>));
```

Then inject this into your validator service.

```
public class CustomerValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    private readonly IScoped<AppDbContext> scopedContext;
    protected AppDbContext DbContext { get } => scopedContext.Instance;

    public CustomValidator(IScoped<AppDbContext> scopedContext)
    {
        this.scopedContext = scopedContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(scopedContext));

        // Access DbContext via this.DbContext
    }
}
```

This way you can inject any scoped service w/o further registrations.

#### Additional notes

Autofac is considered a "conformer" (see [docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)) DI and integrates well with ASP.NET Core and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

From the documentation

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add services to the collection.
    services.AddMvc();

    // Create the container builder.
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register dependencies, populate the services from
    // the collection, and build the container. If you want
    // to dispose of the container at the end of the app,
    // be sure to keep a reference to it as a property or field.
    builder.RegisterType<MyType>().As<IMyType>();
    builder.Populate(services);
    this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

    // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
    return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}
```

There a few subtle differences to the default usage of `Startup` class and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` container.

1. `ConfigureServices` isn't `void` anymore, it returns `IServiceProvider`. This will tell ASP.NET Core to use the returned provider instead of `DefaultServiceProvider` from `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.
2. We return the Autofac container adapter: `new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer)` which is the root container.

This is important to make ASP.NET Core use the container everywhere in ASP.NET Core, even inside middlewares which resolve per request dependencies via `HttpContext.RequestedServices`.

For that reasons you can't use `.InstancePerRequest()` lifetime in Autofac, because Autofac isn't in control of creating scopes and only ASP.NET Core can do it. So there is no easy way to make ASP.NET Core use Autofac's own Request lifetime.

Instead ASP.NET Core will create a new scope (using `IServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope()`) and use a scoped container of Autofac to resolve per-request dependencies.

Comment: First offf this is really clever and works, so thanks, as now at least I'm not stuck! However, is this not Service Locator in diguise? It allows resolution of basically anything.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to have some kind of custom registration. On the other hand, perhaps I can use your solution, but constrain `T` so it is `where T : DbContext` so it only resolves a context.

Comment: Yes and no. The `IScoped<T>` class is part of your infrastructure (same as Autofac and ASP.NET Core), so it's outside of your domain where the logic resides and the domain classes and services have no knowledge of it. The only layer which knows about it is the application layer and only within the composite root, where the concrete `Scope<T>` is registered. All your services still can be easily mocked, since the container is not called in your services only inside `Scoped<T>`. I kept it generic so it can be easily used for every kind of scoped service

Comment: If you would inject `IServiceProvider`/`IHttpContextAccessor`/`IContainer` in every of your domain classes and call `.Resolve` then it would be a true service locator and hard to test/mock it and when the architecture changes, you can easily replace it w/o affecting your domain

Comment: And it's close to the "adapter" pattern, where the container is abstracted behind a factory like class which resolves from the container and except for the concrete implementation, it's container agnostic (well even with the implementation its container agnostic, but specific to request/asp.net core). But its not bulletproof. If you use out outside of the request/httpcontext, it will just blow up like wrongly configured scopes will blow up too in any DI

Comment: For the Autofac registration I assume I need to register as `.SingleInstance()`?

Comment: Two quick followups 1) if I want to depend on Autofac, I tried `IContainer`, `IContainerContext` and `ILifetimeScope` but they are all at the root level, not at the request level scope, so what should I use that is a resolution context for the request (equivalent to what you did with `IHttpContextAccessor`), and also 2) out of curiosity why did you call it `"Scope"` surely it is more accurate to think of it as a `Resolver`?

Comment: Yes, `.SingleInstance()`. There is no easy way to get the scoped container, as ASP.NET Core is controlling it's lifetime and the only way to get it is either via `HttpContext` or via the features collection (that's how `DefaultHttpContext` gets it https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/DefaultHttpContext.cs#L93-L94). However, didn't dig deeper in to see where it's passed to the `DefaultHttpContext` and if you can access it. Autofac is one of the "conformer" DI systems, so you should use `IServiceProvider` like described in the AutoFac documentation

Comment: I guess I'll depend on `IHttpContextAccessor` as you did and keep it simple... thanks Tseng!

Comment: I've updated it with a bit more background information and how 3rd party DI is supposed to be integrated. I called it `IScoped<T>` to make the intent of the class clear, that it will return a scoped instance and it makes it more obvious that there should be special care with using it. You could also call it `IRequestScoped<T>` but this already implies that it's always connected to a request. For a console application you could implement it differently since there is no request, but your domain services shouldn't have to care about it